# Whether the `git log` the first commit is the branch's present commit?

Tags: git

Whether the `git log` the first commit is the branch's present commit?

I use `git log` list the commits:

```
$ git log

commit 75a80c128ea8b28f946b1bd55afa65cc1802bee5
Author: lio <lio@126.com>
Date:   Wed May 9 22:00:35 2018 +0800

    2018-05-09-11

commit a57089b64890e5602a39dc33dc1f07d620d8a870
Merge: c57feb6 9116e2b
Author: lio <lio@126.com>
Date:   Wed May 9 21:52:13 2018 +0800

    Merge branch 'master' of 103.200.32.76:/home/ldl/repo/Qiyun02

commit c57feb677a170d786756c97cb71f6225ba9e6774
Author: lio <lio@126.com>
Date:   Wed May 9 21:48:50 2018 +0800

    2018-05-09-10

commit 9116e2b15605590a2db437bee2f7b83f3f9271ff
Author: root <root@www.lio.xyz>
Date:   Wed May 9 13:47:28 2018 +0800
...
```

whether the first commit `75a80c128ea8b28f946b1bd55afa65cc1802bee5` is the branch's current commit?

Comment: That should be the most recent commit in your local branch. Is that your question?

Comment: What do you mean by 'current commit'?

Comment: @PrasadK the current branch's newest commit.

Comment: Right. So git log will show the commits in reverse chronological order.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct and accurate answer is a bit tricky, but the immediate answer is "yes".  More specifically:

> [In the `git log` output, is the] first commit [shown] the branch's present commit?

Yes, it is.

The reason the complete answer is complicated is that `git log` shows commits one at  a time, and *sometimes* `git log` has two commits that it wants to show simultaneously.  It cannot do so, so it must pick one of the two and show that.  However, running:

```
git log
```

is equivalent to running:

```
git log HEAD
```

which tells `git log` to start by examining the *current commit*.  If the name `HEAD` is attached to a branch name—i.e., if `git status` would say `on branch B` for some *B*—then the current commit is the tip-most commit of branch *B*.  There is always<sup>1</sup> only *one* current commit: there are never *two* current commits, there can only be one.  So with `git log HEAD` or `git log` with no additional arguments, Git starts with that one current commit.

---

<sup>1</sup>Well, *almost* always.  There's a necessary special case.  Suppose you create an *empty* repository, with *no* commits in it yet.  Which commit will be the current commit?  There *aren't any commits yet*, so Git needs a way to allow for *no* commit to be current.  Once there are commits, Git will pick one of them to be current.

You can trigger the special case and go back to having *no* current commit, using `git checkout --orphan`, but that completes the set of cases: there's either one current commit—the usual case—or there is *no* current commit, in a new empty repository or during this special `git checkout --orphan` mode (both of which use the same underlying trick in order to allow the *no current commit* situation).

---

#### The complete and accurate full story

As you can see, every commit has a date-and-time-stamp attached to it:

```
Date:   Wed May 9 22:00:35 2018 +0800
```

In fact, every commit has *two* of these attached time-stamps.  To see both, run `git log --pretty=fuller`.  The `git log` command does not use these dates-and-time-stamps directly, though.  Much more important is the fact that every commit has a *hash ID*, and most commits list one or sometimes two *other* commit hash IDs.  You can see some of these here:

```
commit a57089b64890e5602a39dc33dc1f07d620d8a870
Merge: c57feb6 9116e2b
Author: ...
Date:   ...
```

Note the apparently-random string of digits and letters, `a57089b64890e5602a39dc33dc1f07d620d8a870`.  This is this particular commit's hash ID.  Underneath that is the word `Merge:` and two more strings of digits and letters: `c57feb6` and `9116e2b`.  These are shortened hash IDs, of the two *parent commits* of commit `a57089b...`.

The first big ugly hash ID, `a57089b...`, is the real, true, internal Git name for the commit.  This is how Git accesses the commit.  But to *find* that big ugly hash ID, Git needs some sort of starting point—or rather, an *ending* point.

The ending point, which is where Git started, is commit `75a80c128ea8b28f946b1bd55afa65cc1802bee5`.  Look at the first line of `git log` output, and see the hash ID there.  Git *found* that big ugly hash ID by reading the current *branch name*, such as `master` (whatever branch you actually have checked out).  That *name* stores the hash ID.

Meanwhile, commit `75a80c1...` stores, as its (single) parent hash ID, the ID of *merge commit* `a57089b...`.  So having shown you commit `75a80c1...`, `git log` moves on to commit `a57089b`.  It shows you that commit as the *second* commit shown.  But now Git has *two* commits to show: `c57feb6` and `9116e2b`.

The `git log` command *must* pick one of these two commits to show.  It does so by putting both commits into a [*priority queue*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Priority_queue).  It then picks, out of this queue, the commit with the highest priority.  But which commit *is* that?  Well, that depends on options you pass to `git log`.  The *default* is to sort the queue's contents by `CommitDate` time-stamp (again, use `git log --pretty=fuller` to see these time-stamps), with older commits having higher priority than newer ones.

The `Date:` that you see in ordinary `git log` output is not the `CommitDate` but rather the `AuthorDate`.  To make `git log` sort by this date, use the `--author-date-order` (but note that this implies a topological sort as well).

In any case, the key takeaway here is that the actual time stamps matter *whenever `git log` has more than one commit to show*.  Until then, there is only one commit in the priority queue: Git removes the commit from the queue, shows it, then puts the commit's parent in the queue, giving Git one commit to show.  Git removes the one commit, shows it, puts the parent in, and so on.  It's when you hit a merge commit that this process *automatically* puts at least two commits into the queue.

But if you run `git log branch1 branch2 branch3`, Git starts by putting *three* commits into the priority queue.<sup>2</sup>  Now Git has more than one commit to show, and once again, the time-stamp values come into effect.  This also applies when you run `git log --all` or `git log --branches`, as long as there are multiple references from which `git log` will start.

Hence the rule here is: **as long as you start from `HEAD`, you see the current commit first.**  This is because there is only one current commit, so there's only one commit to show at first, even if it's a merge commit.

---

<sup>2</sup>This assumes that the three branch names point to three different commits, which is not necessarily true—but that's a complication to worry about later.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I suppose, if you are asking about the whether it is the latest commit.

The `git log` command display the commit history of the current branch. 
For example, if you have two branch, master and develop. Develop branch is one commit ahead of master branch, and the newer commit is "fantastic commit". When you checkout master branch and `git log`, it will show you the commit history of master branch, like

`intital commit -> commit1`

Then if you checkout develop branch and `git log`, it will show

`intital commit -> commit1 -> fantastic commit`

But you cannot see the newer commit that is after the `HEAD` commit of the current branch.

I recommend you to use this alias. It display a very beautiful git history. Just add it to you `.gitconfig`.

`[alias]
log --color --graph --pretty=format:'%Cred%h%Creset -%C(yellow)%d%Creset %s %Cgreen(%cr) %C(bold blue)<%an>%Creset' --abbrev-commit`